# Rewrite rule for one or two parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]`

But i want the `id` parameter to be optional … how do i have to write the rule?

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]`

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own attempt looks just fine from the point of view of the rewriting itself. You claim "doesn't work" is nothing we can argue with, but it also does not really help, since it does not say anything about what that means *exactly*.

Assuming that in general rewriting *does* work for you and you only get the wrong (undesired) result I would suggest some slightly altered rule set:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Your rule works just fine. I am not very good in mod_rewrite and regex so what is the difference between (.*) and ([^/]+)?

Comment: Perfomance wise i can image this could have some effect but we are on a generic provider at the moment ... But why should this be a serious security problem? This only affects these two parameters.

Comment: And another question that may be subject for a complete new topic: right now it works when i place the url like ./foo/bar but if i enter ./?page=foo&id=bar it stays like this ... but it should change to the new system (./foo/bar) if a url in the matching syntax is entered

Comment: `(.*)` matches _anything_, `([^/]+)` matches only non empty strings that do not cintain a slash.

Comment: I wrote it is a huge security issues if a php script is allowed to change the `.htaccess` style file. I did not write that their usage itself is a security issue. Reason for the first statement is that _if_ there is _any_ vulnerability in your code, the chances are that a potential attacker can _change_ your code, at least the rewriting to his liking. This _is_ a huge security issue.

Comment: Ah ok. No that is not the case. The rewrite rule doesn't change so i edit this manually once and thats it.

Comment: Your last question indeed is a new topic. That is possible, you use _external_ redirection for that which is also possible by means of the rewriting module. You do however need somewhat more complex rules involving a condition. I suggest you ask a separate question, or, even better, first look for answers of what you ask here on SO since that is a standard thing.

Comment: Ok, glad to head that you care about that security issue I mentioned. However the fact that is the "does not change" does not help. The important things is to take care that your scripts are not _able_ to modify these files. Best is to use file system based permissions for that.

Comment: Thank you for that note and your great answers +1